# How to create events for buttons created while runtime?

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, button

I have an application with a gui, where I create some buttons not with the designer, but while runetime in code.

I need some click events for these buttons. Is there a way to make the events without the designer? Maybe it is a noob question, but i haven't done this before and i didn't got the point searching msdn.

Comment: What system, language, GUI framework etc. are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was really too easy.

I just added a Button with the designer and looked what code the designer generated.

I only had to create the button, implement the event method and then add a new Click Event to the button with reference to the method.

```
    this.btnSaveSignal = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnSaveSignal.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSaveSignal_Click);
    .
    .
    .
    private void btnSaveSignal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

That was all. It works.